# Result discrepancy between cv.MinAreaRect2 and ArcGIS (GIS software) . Possible bug?

Tags: python, debugging, opencv, geometry

I have a set of points derived from a polygon. I am testing several solution in order to obtain the minimum area or the rectangle. As benchmark I am using ArcGIS (10.1).

```
points = [(560036.4495758876, 6362071.890493258),
          (560036.4495758876, 6362070.890493258),
          (560036.9495758876, 6362070.890493258),
          (560036.9495758876, 6362070.390493258),
          (560037.4495758876, 6362070.390493258),
          (560037.4495758876, 6362064.890493258),
          (560036.4495758876, 6362064.890493258),
          (560036.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
          (560035.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
          (560035.4495758876, 6362062.390493258),
          (560034.9495758876, 6362062.390493258),
          (560034.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
          (560032.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
          (560032.9495758876, 6362061.890493258),
          (560030.4495758876, 6362061.890493258),
          (560030.4495758876, 6362061.390493258),
          (560029.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
          (560029.9495758876, 6362060.390493258),
          (560029.4495758876, 6362060.390493258),
          (560029.4495758876, 6362059.890493258),
          (560028.9495758876, 6362059.890493258),
          (560028.9495758876, 6362059.390493258),
          (560028.4495758876, 6362059.390493258),
          (560028.4495758876, 6362058.890493258),
          (560027.4495758876, 6362058.890493258),
          (560027.4495758876, 6362058.390493258),
          (560026.9495758876, 6362058.390493258),
          (560026.9495758876, 6362057.890493258),
          (560025.4495758876, 6362057.890493258),
          (560025.4495758876, 6362057.390493258),
          (560023.4495758876, 6362057.390493258),
          (560023.4495758876, 6362060.390493258),
          (560023.9495758876, 6362060.390493258),
          (560023.9495758876, 6362061.890493258),
          (560024.4495758876, 6362061.890493258),
          (560024.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
          (560024.9495758876, 6362063.390493258),
          (560024.9495758876, 6362064.390493258),
          (560025.4495758876, 6362064.390493258),
          (560025.4495758876, 6362065.390493258),
          (560025.9495758876, 6362065.390493258),
          (560025.9495758876, 6362065.890493258),
          (560026.4495758876, 6362065.890493258),
          (560026.4495758876, 6362066.890493258),
          (560026.9495758876, 6362066.890493258),
          (560026.9495758876, 6362068.390493258),
          (560027.4495758876, 6362068.390493258),
          (560027.4495758876, 6362068.890493258),
          (560027.9495758876, 6362068.890493258),
          (560027.9495758876, 6362069.390493258),
          (560028.4495758876, 6362069.390493258),
          (560028.4495758876, 6362069.890493258),
          (560033.4495758876, 6362069.890493258),
          (560033.4495758876, 6362070.390493258),
          (560033.9495758876, 6362070.390493258),
          (560033.9495758876, 6362070.890493258),
          (560034.4495758876, 6362070.890493258),
          (560034.4495758876, 6362071.390493258),
          (560034.9495758876, 6362071.390493258),
          (560034.9495758876, 6362071.890493258),
          (560036.4495758876, 6362071.890493258)]
```

One solution is use `cv.MinAreaRect2()` of OpenCV.

> The function cv.MinAreaRect2 finds a circumscribed rectangle of the
>   minimal area for 2D point set by building convex hull for the set and
>   applying rotating calipers technique to the hull.

```
import cv
# (x,y) - center point of the box
# (w,h) - width and height of the box
# theta - angle of rotation
((x,y),(w,h),th) = cv.MinAreaRect2(points)
print ((x,y),(w,h),th)
((560029.3125, 6362065.5), (10.28591251373291, 18.335756301879883), -63.43495178222656)
# get vertex
box_vtx = cv.BoxPoints(((x,y),(w,h),th))
print box_vtx 
((560035.1875, 6362074.0), (560018.8125, 6362066.0), (560023.4375, 6362057.0), (560039.8125, 6362065.0)
```

when I convert `box_vtx` in a shapefile in order to view in ArcGIS and compare with [Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000)I can see this difference as shown in the following picture, 
where:

- red = border of polygon
- blue = rectangle with minimum area from ArGIS (10.1)
- yellow and black =  rectangle with minimum area from OpenCV

[image]

Working with OpenCV compared with solution proposed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542855/python-help-to-implement-an-algorithm-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-gi):

```
import osgeo.gdal, ogr
import cv

poly = "...\\polygon.shp"
shp = osgeo.ogr.Open(poly)
layer = shp.GetLayer()
feature = layer.GetFeature(0)
geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
pts = geometry.GetGeometryRef(0)
# get point of the polygon border (the points above)
points = []
for p in xrange(pts.GetPointCount()):
    points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
# Convex Hull
CH1 = geometry.ConvexHull
# i didn't find a method to extarct  the points
print CH1()
# works with openCV
cvxHull = cv.ConvexHull2(points, cv.CreateMemStorage(), return_points=True) 
print cvxHull
<cv2.cv.cvseq object at 0x00000000067CCF90>
```

Comment: What's the primary reason you're doing this..creating an alternative to ArcGIS, just testing OpenCV?

Comment: @martineau: I am doing a script (simple) in Python to extract several indexes from a polygon shapefile. i am doing this for several recursions: 1- ArcGIS is really expensive (more than 8000$) and i need only to calculate the Lenght and Width. 2- create a specific script that i can modify (ex: adding new indices), 3- learning. I know the theory says: if there is a tested function use that function (i was thinking OpenCv was a tested function)

Comment: There are (obviously) two major steps in computing the minimum enclosing rectangular area of a convex hull around an arbitrary set of points. I think a good approach (which jwpat7 also seems to also be saying) would be to check each step separately -- which means first determining if there is a significant difference between the convex hulls derived from the points -- and it's not clear to me if you've done that already or not.

Comment: @martineau. thanks your effort I am doing step by step. Some pint are dark in OpenCV. Example after cv.ConvexHull2(points, cv.CreateMemStorage(), return_points=True) , i cannot find a mwthod to extract the point value in order to compare with convehll of import osgeo.gdal, ogr

Comment: @martineau; you can see the code update

Comment: @martineau. sorry if i am enable, really sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at OpenCV code, but it seems likely that large x,y products are being subtracted from other large x,y products in its calculations.  The offsets in your x values use about 19 bits, and those of y about 23, so such subtraction can result in a loss of about 42 bits from the 53 that typical double precision numbers carry. (See [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Range_of_floating-point_numbers) in wikipedia.)  The size and shape of the yellow and black rectangle look reasonable but the displayed width and length, (10.285..., 18.335...) are 1% different from (10.393, 18.037), the width and length that appeared in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553884).

In short, OpenCV may have a rounding, underflow, or overflow problem in `MinAreaRect2()` or in `BoxPoints()`.

Things to check or tests to develop include:
• Display and print the points of OpenCV's convex hull computation
• On the graph, display the centers of OpenCV's and ArcGIS's rectangles, and print distances from those centers to the corners of the displayed rectangles
• Rerun the computations and graph with a translated data set (see below), to reduce the underflow effect of subtracting large numbers from each other

Translating the data set before the OpenCV computation can cut the number of bits lost in half.  Produce a new set of points via code like the following, and try the computation with the new data set:

```
s = points     # points = original data set
n = len(s)
cx = sum(zip(*s)[0])/n
cy = sum(zip(*s)[1])/n
points = map(lambda p: (p[0]-cx, p[1]-cy), s)
# Now points = translated data set
```

In the above code, `zip(*s)` unzips the list of (x,y) points into two lists, with the x values listed in zip(*s)[0] and the y values listed in zip(*s)[1].  Thus (cx,cy) represents the center of mass of points listed in s.  The map expression applies a function to elements of an iterable.  The function returns a point translated by (-cx,-cy).  The value of the map expression is a list of translated points.  Note, it might be preferable to set `cx = int(sum(zip(*s)[0])/n)` and `cy = int(sum(zip(*s)[1])/n)` so that lattice points remain lattice points, if that is what you are computing with.  The beneficial effect of removing large offsets remains, and less rounding will occur during translation.

*Note –* I ran tests with offsets subtracted from the data set and from the hull (supposing the hull is as shown in  [question #13542855](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542855/python-help-to-implement-an-algorithm-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-gi) and perhaps in  [question #13553884](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553884/python-implement-a-script-in-a-function-some-suggestions)) and got inconsistent results that do not agree well with results from the method I gave in #13542855.  Thus it is difficult to pin down where the problem is occurring based on your numbers.  A simpler test case is shown below.  This test makes it clear that large offsets cause poor accuracy.  Perhaps you could run similar test data via ArcGIS.  Following are half of the results from the test.  MinAreaRect2() and BoxPoints() were given base numbers with offsets added; for the displayed results, the offset is subtracted back off after the calculation so that results can be compared easily.  Ideally, all of the numbers in each column (except ox,oy columns) would be the same; but as ox,oy increase, they begin to differ and soon become nearly random.

```
      ox         oy      T cx      T cy    height     width     theta
       0          0    6.2500    7.7500   11.5709   13.7281  -78.6901
      64        125    6.2500    7.7500   11.5709   13.7281  -78.6901
     256        625    6.2500    7.7501   11.5709   13.7281  -78.6901
    1024       3125    6.2500    7.7500   11.5709   13.7281  -78.6901
    4096      15625    6.2500    7.7510   11.5709   13.7281  -78.6901
   16384      78125    6.2500    7.7578   11.5709   13.7281  -78.6901
   65536     390625    6.2500    7.7812   11.5709   13.7281  -78.6901
  262144    1953125    6.3125    7.7500   11.5709   13.7281  -78.6901
 1048576    9765625    6.2500    8.0000   11.5709   13.7281  -78.6901
 4194304   48828125    7.0000   11.0000   12.0000   14.0000  -90.0000
16777216  244140625    8.0000   15.0000   16.0000   14.0000  -90.0000
67108864 1220703125    8.0000  -21.0000   16.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
```

Here is the code that produced the data shown above:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv
base = [(1,1), (0,4), (2,9), (5,11), (8,14), (13,9), (14,4), (12,3), (2,1), (1,1)]
ox, oy, boxes = 0, 0, []
print '        ox         oy      T cx      T cy    height     width     theta'
for i in range(3,15):
    poly = map(lambda p: (p[0]+ox, p[1]+oy), base)
    (x,y), (w,h), th = cv.MinAreaRect2(poly)
    boxes.append((ox, oy, cv.BoxPoints(((x,y),(w,h),th))))
    print ('{:10d} {:10d} {:9.4f} {:9.4f} {:9.4f} {:9.4f} {:9.4f}'.format(
            ox, oy, x-ox, y-oy, w, h, th))
    ox, oy = 4**i, 5**i

print '\n        ox         oy       T x       T y       T x       T y       T x       T y       T x       T y'
for (ox, oy, box) in boxes:
    print '{:10d} {:10d}'.format(ox, oy),
    for p in box:
        print '{:9.4f} {:9.4f}'.format(p[0]-ox, p[1]-oy),
    print
```

Comment: Dear jwpat7. Do you think i need to send a feedback to OpenCV people?

Comment: PS: the life is not easy. This morning i was super happy to find a solution to calculate minor and major axis. I am honest. Yesterday night i tried to compact your approach in one single function, but I am really a beginner in Python programming and i am not able with my actual capacity

Comment: @Gianni: It's not clear to me from your comment if you were able to try these suggestions or not (and whether they helped). Also, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 on Window machine. I download OpenCV from this page Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Question is if OpenCV has a bug. I am using ArcGIS (really expensive software to work with spatial data) as Benchmark

Comment: @Gianni: Did any of jwpat7's suggestions improve your results?

Comment: @martineau: jwpat7 is really great and talent. i tried but not appreciate improvement. Probably the best is use  jwpat7-martineau function. OpenCV is really a milestone, it's strange this discrepancy with ArcGIS

Comment: @Gianni: What are you using to get the convex hull of this set of points?

Comment: @martineau. In ArcGis is inside the module (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000). But i think is the same approach of module
from shapely.geometry import Polygon (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely)

Comment: @martineau. I tested cv.MinAreaRect2() with polygon vertex and Convex Hull vertex (= extract by shapely) and the result is always the same

Comment: Dear jwpat7, thanks for your effort (and thanks to @martineau too). I can image how hard is coding with data (i have problem also with data). Compliment again. I cannot figure out to resolve this problem. I am honest to say it's out of by know-out. In this link http://ge.tt/19XOxNS/v/0?c you can download the data of the example (the shapefile in *.shp). You can load following my example.

Comment: Dear jwpat7 and @martineau, thanks for your time, but i don't wish abuse of you.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread while looking for a Python solution for a minimum-area bounding rectangle.

Here's my implementation, which has been verified with Matlab: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14675742/1755401